# Windows Forms - Is it possible to programmatically see if the windows start screen is open in a windows form?

Tags: .net, windows, winforms

I was wondering if it was possible for a windows forms app to know if the Start screen was open in Windows 10?

I've looked through the internet, but have found nothing on it. Is there something like a `Windows.isStartScreenOpen()` method in winForms or .net generally?

Comment: By Start Screen, are you meaning the Windows Menu button?

Comment: Read the Remarks section of [LockWorkStation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-lockworkstation?redirectedfrom=MSDN)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when you press the Start button (Windows Key) the title of the active window becomes "Cortana", and it's class name becomes "Windows.UI.Core.CoreWindow"; you could test for those being the active window. One way would be to add a timer to your form that constantly checks if the active window title and class name match those, and if yes, set a flag, then you can just check the flag as necessary.

You'll have to use the WinAPI to get the active window title/classname (there are examples on these pages as well):

https://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32.GetWindowText

https://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32.GetClassName